# How to handle empty URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do you set up the routing to handle http://mysite.com/Foo?

Where foo can be any value.  I want it to go to /Home/Action/Id where foo is the id.

These are the mappings I have tried:

```
        routes.MapRoute("Catchall", "{*catchall}", 
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id=""});

        routes.MapRoute("ByKey", "{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" id=""});
```

They both generated a 404.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (note you had a missing comma in your original post):

```
routes.MapRoute("ByKey", "{id}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id=""});
```

I would, however, make it a bit more explanatory to prevent clashes later, even if it means a bit longer URIs:

```
routes.MapRoute("ByKey", "ByKey/{id}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id=""});
```

And place this as the first MapRoute command. Order does matter there, and the first route you add is the first route for a URL to be tested with.

Answer (score 1):

Your second route is correct. It should work. Maybe you have another routes above? Debug your routes with [Phil Haack's ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: I believe unit tests does the trick better. Have you tried MvcContrib routing test helpers? :)

Comment: Something like `"~/foo".Route().ShouldMapTo<HomeController>(x => x.Index("foo"));` would be interesting. You should post an answer too

Comment: But I dont understand how it helps David if this test fails?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve
Right click on the project
Go to web tab of the page.
My Start URL was found to be empty
I copied what in Project url of Servers section
Pasted at Start Url

It worked.

Comment: This is 10-years old question with answers. Question is related to configuration of routes, controllers and actions. It is not clear to me how your answer is related to the question - I do not see in your answer any mention of controllers and actions.  If you think that you can add good up-to-date answer then please add explanation to your answer.